# Run PHP file from adminform when button is clicked

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, adminform

I have created one module. That module has a form, which has a button field. If that button is clicked then I want to run php file.

That file I have put in the root folder in magento with name test.php.

How to do this, if button is clicked, then call test.php to run?

[image]

Comment: Which php code you are using in that test.php file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work w/o adding `index.php`.

```
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'test.php'

$fieldset->addField('yourfield', 'button', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Button Label'),
    'value' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Button Caption'),
    'name'  => 'yourfield',
    'class' => 'form-button',
    'onclick' => "setLocation('{$url}')",
));
```